# Spring multipart upload

Tags: java, forms, spring, file-upload, multipart

Im trying to write a controller and a form that can handle a multipart file upload and some other data passing.
First i made the basic form like this:

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="myForm">
```

then everything fine, but no multipart handling of course. Then i add the enctype part like this:

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Then my whole form is messed up and all the attribuets gives NullPointers. Not even a simple String name attribute working. Also i added:

```
<beans:bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />
```

So i really got no idea whats the problem. Any comment would help a lot. Thnaks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We are using CommonsMultipartResolver in our project. It goes like this. In your applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1048576000"/>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>
```

Then cast yout request to MultipartHttpServletRequest:

```
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws Exception {
    if (!(req instanceof MultipartHttpServletRequest)) {
        error(resp, "Invalid request (multipart request expected)");
        return null;
    }
Map<String, MultipartFile> files = ((MultipartHttpServletRequest)req).getFileMap();
... do thomething with the files
```

Comment: I'm getting ClassCastException now, but i think my problem is mainly that when i add enctype then my fomr goes crazy and spring cant handle it somehow, but dont know why, i added the same bean as you did and not working...

Comment: enctype is essential for file uploads, you can't get rid of them. The error must be trivial: you edited the wrong file, or didn't add "implements Controller" or something

Comment: true thing. of course i edited the wrong xml... hate it when i get these little errors and debugging them for hours...
Anyway, thanks for the help ;)